# AlarmManager not starting Activity (when it exists)

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Here's what I have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(context,SomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pending  = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,requestCode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, someDistantMillis, someIntervalInMillis,pending);
```

It works OK, that is Activity is launched at `someDistantMillis` and repeatedly launched after `someIntervalInMillis`

The only problem is that, if `SomeActivity` already is running after `someIntervalInMillis` another instance of `SomeActivity` is launched on top of the stack.

Here's briefly what I want to achieve:

1. Strart, `AlarmManager` is called
2. if instance of `SomeActivity` is already running then goto 4) else goto 3)
3. Launch `SomeActivity`, end
4. do nothing, end

Any ideas how it should be done, or what flags should the `Intent` inclued (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` does not appear to work)?

Comment: try with adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` into activity tag in manifest.

Comment: Is SomeActivity the root activity (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) of your app?

Comment: @PankajKumar please don't suggest `launchMode="singleInstance"` without getting a lot of other data first. Using this launch mode may solve this specific problem, but will likely create a whole lot of other issues for the user. In general, singleInstance launch mode should only be used in very special circumstances (for example: HOME-screen replacement). IMHO this is bad advice.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you for your valuable comment. Will take care. I was not aware of negative sides. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a static `boolean` member field in your `Activity`:

```
public static boolean running = false;
```

In `onStart()` method set `running` to `true` and in `onStop()` to `false`. Then in a place where you want to determine if your `Activity` is running, just do this `if` statement:

```
if(SomeActivity.running) {
   // go to step 4
} else {
   // go to step 3
}
```

`static` keyword is crucial here, as it means the `running` field will be common for all instances of `SomeActivity` class, therefore you don't need access to specific `SomeActivity`'s object.

Comment: Good idea, guess if nothing better coms along it will the way to go. Is there a more "Android approach" to handle this? I don't like the idea of being dependent on some static variable.

Comment: Notice that when you switch between the apps and then try to relaunch a specific app, the system knows whether to resume an Activity from the background or launch a new one, so there must be some lower-level logic to handle this from the SDK